# What is the difference between high voltage/current PCB tracing?

Tags: pcb, pcb-design

What is the difference between designing PCB traces for carrying high voltage in comparison to traces carrying high current? Would there be any difference in how they are drawn (such as trace width, thickness, isolation from other traces and etc.)? I'd preferably have an answer that would explain the constraints and limitations in simple words of a basic level.

Comment: This had the potential to become a good question...

Answer (score 3):

Generally, high voltage design requires more space between copper tracks and high current design requires wider/thicker tracks.

Comment: thx but can u tell me every thing about the differance ?

Comment: There is no difference -- they are orthogonal issues. And no, a complete treatise on PCB design would be too long for the Q&A format we use here.

Comment: plz give me any source or book  tallking about 
high current/ voltage design on pcb ?

Comment: Product recommendations are off-topic here, too.

Answer (score 2):

The theoretical spacing for external layer uncoated high voltage traces is usually limited by the breakdown voltage of air.  The breakdown voltage of air is roughly 30kV per cm, which works out to 76V / mil.

So for example, an arc would form between two external uncoated traces spaced 10 mils apart for any voltage more than 760V.

Practically speaking one would usually use much more than the minimum theoretical spacing in my example for the following reasons.

1)  There is tolerance when fabricating the board.
2)  The breakdown voltage can be lower depending on humidity.
3)  The breakdown voltage can be lower if there is any kind of surface contamination on the board.  One can't always count on the fact that dust won't settle on the board after its been installed somewhere for 10 years.
4)  There are many different safety standards which require much more spacing, and if you want to have UL or other agency approval you will need to meet those guidelines.

The IPC-2221 specification, and the Underwriters Laboratories give spacing guidelines that back off from the physical limits quite a bit.

For traces on internal layers or if coatings are used, then the spacing may be reduced.

Comment: Creepage along the surface of the PCB is much more significant than the breakdown voltage of the air. Surface contaminants accumulate even in the cleanest environments, and they tend to be somewhat conductive, especially in the presence of moisture. Spacing rules take this into account.

Answer (score 1):

High voltage you add wider track spacing, occasional slots in the board, conformal coating or potting and use better quality materials.  High current you use wider tracks and thicker plating and more vias and sometimes additional buses. At times you have to use both.